# Download file from a link Webview Android

Tags: java, android, webview

my app shows an HTML page that contains a link. I would like to download the file from that link. How can I do? (The link is not always the same).

---

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String webUrl = webview.getUrl();                                     

            final String html = "<html>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ycapi.org/js/link.js\"></script>\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<div>\n" +
                    "    Example (mp3 / href):\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <br>\n" +
                    "    <a href="+webUrl+" target=\"_blank\" class=\"y2m\">Developers</a>\n" +
                    "</div>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "</html>" +
                    "";
            final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "http://....index.html");
            webview.loadData(String.valueOf(doc),"text/html", "UTF-8");             


    }
    });
```

Comment: Hi @th3gr3yman, on click of the link you can redirect to a download link which will automatically start downloading file to your phone.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I saw that in the method to download I have to pass the url,but this url changes every time...

Comment: Can you share your code and the html page, so that i can get a clear picture ?